# Is it possible to view reddit as normal forum website?

Tags: reddit, forums

Reddit has a horrible design as a website. I do not understand how it became so popular then. But it often happens that Google searches leads to some reddit thread which looks very relevant for me.

The problem is that when I want to read the web page, reddit tries to make me see as much other threads as possible, while not showing completely a thread which I am interested in. There are lots of "Continue this thread" links during the thread, like on this picture:

[image]

If I press it, then I loose the upper level of thread. So I need to open that link in new tab. But there is a lot of similar links on each level. So you go deeper and deeper (like a recursion), and really loose control of where you came from. And your tab bar also becomes overbloated by many pieces of thread in a different tabs.

And this happens nearly for every thread I am trying to read on reddit.

On Android the site is also unreadable. It spams me telling to install their application, which practically does not help. But I have found a solution - an *Infinity for Reddit* application, which does exactly what I want (all threads on one page without any Continue this thread links).

The question is for PC side now. **Is there any browser extension or any other solution which allows visitors to read the site as a human readable forum** (bbs)?

Comment: Just use `old.reddit.com`.